# How to find and enumerate the number of perfect matchings in directed complete graphs?

Tags: graph-theory

I would like to enumerate all perfect matchings, of the complete directed graph K2n. Knowing that for the undirected graph there is a blossom algorithm, but it's applied to the undirected graph, not for the directed graph!!
 Is there an algorithm or method to enumerate all the perfect matchings in a directed graph?

Comment: How is a directed perfect matching different from an undirected one? I don't think the directions on the edges change anything, unless you have some other requirements? See https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/62526/complexity-of-finding-a-perfect-matching-in-directed-graphs for the ambiguity. The first case ignores the directions, the second sounds trivial.

Comment: yes, but I need to find all the perfect matching of a graph where for exapmle in K4: the perfect matching (1,2) (3,4) dont equal to (2,1) (3,4)

Comment: Unless I'm confused about the complete directed graph, isn't that just $2^n$ (the direction choices) time's the number of matchings of the corresponding undirected graph?

Comment: yes it's but as what i mentioned the algorithm applied on the undirected graph to find all the perfect matching's (blossom algorithm) it's not applied on the directed graph therefore I need an algorithm or method o find minimum weighed  perfect matching in the directed graph. moreover for an instance of four nods the both perfect matchings: (1,2),(3,4)  and (2,1), (3,4)are different??

Comment: And I told you how to modify blossoms algorithm... Take your complete directed graph, remove the directions on the edges, and run blossoms. If you combine edges that differ only on direction, multiply the output by $2^n$, if you keep parallel edges, just return the result.

Comment: thanks is a good idea but the weight of the edge (i,j) is not equal to the wheight the edge (j, i)? in this case how can I applied the blossom algorithm which weigh I should choose in the undirected graph?

Comment: your question isn't about weighted perfect matchings, and the usual blossom algorithm is for an unweighted graph. Ignoring that, weather you want a maximum or a minimum matching, Blossom's algorithm works for graphs with parallel edges and weights, you need only to ignore the direction of the edges.